# Is it possible to create a CStringT struct in x32dbg/x64dbg to make them more readable?

Tags: x64dbg

I'm working on analyzing a program which makes extensive use of CStringT but I am unclear as to how these are represented in memory, as it does not seem to be consistent. For example using a x32dbg, we may see EAX as follows:

```
EAX : 004FD62C <&??_7?$CStringT@_W@Foo@@6B@>
```

But sometimes when I go to dump 004FD62C, what I find there is a string, other times its just a series of pointers that seem to lead to no printable text. Is there a way to make analyzing these easier in x32dbg? Since they are variable length I'm thinking no, but figured someone might know.

thx